# How to import dependent plugin class

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Let's suppose I'm working on eclipse with 2 plugins a and b. 
a requires b (on a -> manifest.mf -> dependencies -> add and then select the b plugin)

Let's say b contains a class B

Now in a a class I want to instantiate a B obj. On this purpose I have no problems importing b package but I can't see its B class (and obviously I can't instantiate any B object).

How can I import b.B class?

Thanks a lot

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

Plugin b must export the packages that it wants other plugins to be able to use.

To do this open the MANIFEST.MF editor and choose the Runtime tab. Use the Add button to add the packages to export to the Exported Packages list.